# How do I get the CSS font-size in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.fontSize
```

However that returns nothing. My CSS is defined in the same document and not a separate stylesheet. 
I have also tried this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("content");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
el.style.fontSize = (fontSize + 1) + "px";
```

but that doesn't work.

This is the html in question:

```
<p contenteditable="true" id="content">Write here. Seriously, try it.</p>
```

And this is the css

```
#content {
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 22px;
    min-height: 90%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    font-size:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try passing the element to the [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('foo')).fontSize
```